# How to call this method in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, web-services, asynchronous

I am making a VB.NET application which uses SOAP web service.
It works very well in synchronous mode using run method.
But I would like to use this asynchronous method :

```
Public Overloads Sub runAsync(ByVal callContext As CAdxCallContext, ByVal publicName As String, ByVal inputXml As String, ByVal userState As Object)
  If (Me.runOperationCompleted Is Nothing) Then
      Me.runOperationCompleted = AddressOf Me.OnrunOperationCompleted
 End If
 Me.InvokeAsync("run", New Object() {callContext, publicName, inputXml},   Me.runOperationCompleted, userState)
End Sub
```

How to call it ?

How to indicate the callback method ?

thank you

Piotr

Comment: What's wrong with the sample code you provided. `Me.runOperationCompleted` would be the callback method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, it put me on the right track.

I found how to call and get the callback using asynchronous method :

call :

```
x3WebService.runAsync(callContext, webserv, params, UserState)
```

callback :

```
Public Sub RunAsyncCompleted(sender As Object, e As runCompletedEventArgs) Handles x3WebService.runCompleted
```

...

But you have to declare "withevents" the x3WebService class :

```
Public Class X3WebServices
  Private WithEvents x3WebService As CAdxWebServiceXmlCCServiceBasicAuth
```

Good day to you,

Piotr

Answer (score 0):

`TaskCompletionSource` would be right tool to wrap event based methods with the asynchronous one.

Create completion event handler which accepts instance of `TaskCompletionSource` as an argument.

```
Public Sub OperationCompleted(
  e As SomeEventArgs, 
  TaskCompletionSource(Of SoapResult) taskSource
)
  ' Use EventArgs of your client to determine were operation successful or not
  ' Here I am using common completion properties
  If e.Cancelled Then
    taskSource.TrySetCanceled()
    Exit Sub
  End If

  If e.HasError Then
    taskSource.TrySetException(e.Error)
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ' Should be success now
  taskSource.TrySetResult(e.Result) ' Result is an instance of type SoapResult
End Sub
```

Asynchronous method returns Task, in this example we expect instance o `SoapResult` type to be returned when operation succeeds.

```
Public Function RunAsync(MyInputArguments args) As Task(Of SoapResult)
  Dim taskSource As New TaskCompletionSource(Of SoapResult)()

  Dim invokeArgs As New Object() { args.Context, args.PublicName, args.InputXml }

  ' Wrap our completion handler with the function 
  ' To satisfy soap callback signature
  Dim callback As Action(Of SomeEventArgs) = 
    Sub(e) Me.OperationCompleted(e, taskSource)

  InvokeAsync("run", invokeArgs, callback, args.UserState)

  Return taskSource.Task
End Function
```

Now we can asynchronously invoke Soap client with `async-await`

```
Dim arguments As New With
{
  .Context = callContext,
  .PublicName = publicName,
  .InputXml = inputXml,
  .UserState = userState
}
Dim result As SoapResult = Await client.RunAsync(arguments)
```